# WSO2 IoT server manager returns 403 error on login

Tags: java, jsp, wso2, http-status-code-403

I've got an issue to connect to IoT manager:

https://127.0.0.1:9443/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp

Here's the error:

> [IoT-Core]  WARN - {org.owasp.csrfguard.log.JavaLogger} potential
> cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attack thwarted (user:,
> ip:127.0.0.1, method:POST, uri:/carbon/admin/login_action.jsp,
> error:required token is missing from the request)

I run 3.1.0 verion.

> [root@srv-wso2 wso2iot-3.1.0]# java -version
>
> java version "1.8.0_151"
> Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12) Java HotSpot(TM)
> 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this recently. It was due to a gzip decoding issue with JDK `1.8.0_151`. Please try with `1.8.0_144`. It should work.

Comment: @Bhathiya could you please specify / link the issue? A problem with gzip encoding may have other consequences as well so I am curious how serious it is and when it happens

Comment: This is the original issue. https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8189789
 Works fine with JDK 8u162-ea.